# How to use SHA-3 on Mac? Which hash function securely prove integrity of files?

Tags: macos, hash, md5, sha

I need do make a digital attachment to my master thesis thus I was looking into hash functions to proof integrity. I thought of supplying all (MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256) and I'd also love to supply a SHA-3 as well.

How can I calculate a SHA-3 on mac?

Do you think SHA-3 is necessary and recommended or would the others be proof enough?

Which other hash algorithms would you recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in Go which has SHA-3 as part of its crypto library.